# DICCIONARIO DENTRO DE UNA LISTA

Tags: python-3.x, lista, diccionarios, jupyter

estoy con un archivo csv, que ha sido abierto con DictReader, es una lista de estudiantes, uno de los ejercicios es poner sólo los nombres de los estudiantes (sin apellidos) evitando que estén los nombres repetidos y contabilizarlos. El tipo de dato es una lista que está dentro de un diccionario. Os paso lo que he hecho

```
 suma=0
 for row in datos:
     if row['FirstName'] not in row:
         suma+=1
         print(row['FirstName'])
 print('El resulatdo es',suma)
```

Y el resultado no es el correcto porque pone todos los nombres(y los hay repetidos) y suma el total. Me imagino el fallo ya que 'FirstName' está en todos los elementos de la lista y yo lo que busco son los valores de 'FirstName'. Si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradecería

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren dos modos de hacerlo:

1.- Use la función `set()` para contar los valores únicos en la lista Python
`set()` es un tipo de datos de recolección no ordenada que es iterable, mutable, y no tiene elementos duplicados. Podemos obtener la longitud del set para contar los valores `unique` en la lista, después de convertir la lista en un set usando la función `set()`. Por ejemplo:

```
words = ['Z', 'V', 'A', 'Z','V']
print(len(set(words)))
```

Y 2.- `numpy.unique` devuelve los valores únicos de el array de entrada como datos, y también devuelve el recuento de cada valor único si el parámetro `return_counts` está configurado como `True`. Por ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np
words = ['Z', 'V', 'A', 'Z','V']
np.unique(words)
print(len(np.unique(words)))
```

Comment: He probado su primer aporte y me la lista de los nombres separados letra a letra y cuenta todos los elementos, no es el resultado que debe dar, debe dar una lista de nombres (sólo los nombres, sin los apellidos), que no sean repetidos y contarlos

Comment: Si puedes aportar el origen de los datos ayudaría mucho (una muestra o ejemplo, no hace falta que sean los datos originales).

Comment: He vuelto a probar lo que respondí, incluyendo palabras en vez de letras, y funciona bien. La función no cambia la lista, solo cuenta los items 'unicos' que hay en la lista. Si me indicas como es la lista que contiene los datos, podremos averiguar algo más.

Comment: Es una lista que contiene diccionarios dentro, cada elemento de la lista es un diccionario con el nombre de una escuela, los nombres de los alumnos, año de graduación y email

Comment: Ah!, ok, entonces debe convertir previamente los valores del diccionario en una lista usando 'listOfValues = dictionary.values()', y pasar la lista obtenida como parámetro a la función 'set()'. La función 'set()' sobre un diccionario actua de forma diferente (solo extrae las keys(), no los 'values()')

Comment: No habría que hacer entonces ningún bucle?

Comment: En principio, no es necesario, y además es más rápido y eficiente. Una de las ventajas de python ;-)

Comment: Pues me sigue dando errores, da igual,  muchas gracias pero necesito avanzar. Ahora tengo otro problema al importar Panda me da error, ¿tiene que ver con la versión de python que tengo instalada?

Comment: Siempre es una buena opción tener actualizada la última versión de cualquier software que uses. Evitarás errores y tendrás a tu disposición los últimos comandos.

Comment: Respecto el problema al importar... sin saber como son tus datos en origen es difícil averiguar lo que sucede. Parece extraño que estén en un .csv, y los leas con un diccionario, pero... no puedo ayudar sin más información.